# Jquery Plupload big file upload fail

Tags: php, jquery

im using plupload and php clas for resize http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_docs.htm

everything goes well, but when i upload big file 4000x2000 px with only 250kb, the upload fails. the class for resize has its on limeter for maximum width and height, but it is set to NULL, so its not checking it for causing cancel of upload.

my code in AJAX handler is this.

```
$foo = new Upload($_FILES['file']);
    if ($foo->uploaded)
    {
        $new_name = functions::getRandomString(16);

        $foo->file_new_name_body = 'b_' . $new_name;
        if ($foo->image_src_x > 800 or $foo->image_src_y > 600)
        {
        $foo->image_resize = true;
        $foo->image_ratio = true;
        $foo->image_y = 600;
        $foo->image_x = 800;
        }
        $foo->image_convert = 'png';
        $foo->Process($upload_path);
        if ($foo->processed)
        {
        //echo 'image renamed "foo" copied';
        }
        else
        {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Chyba prejmenovani."}, "id" : "id"}');
        }
```

AND jquery

```
$("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
    // General settings
    runtimes : 'html5,html4',
    url : '/core/ajax/ajax_upload.php',
    max_file_size : '10mb',
    chunk_size : '5mb',
    unique_names : true,
    /*
    resize : {width : 320, height : 240, quality : 90},
    */
    // Specify what files to browse for
    filters : [
    {
        title : "Image files", 
        extensions : "jpg,jpeg,gif,png"
    }]

    });
```

and the JSON response for this concrete file upload session

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator,
```

Comment: Can you share the output at various points in your file? It can be helpful to debug using `die()` statements and figuring out exactly at which point your script file is failing.

Answer (score 0):

There are chances that limit would have been put on the file size by the PHP configuration, try having a look at Apache error log to view the exact problem.

Or

You can also using `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to view the maxium upload filesize

Comment: Please do `not` add random code formatting to random `words` in your posts.  It makes them hard to read.

Comment: post_max_size 8M, upload_max_filesize 10M.

Comment: [Thu Dec 27 01:23:55 2012] [warn] [client 1111] mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 134874 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (131072), referer: http://www..../
[Thu Dec 27 01:23:55 2012] [error] [client 1111] File does not exist: dev/www..../error, referer: http://www..../57/

Answer (score 0):

i changed the value for 10000000 for this virtual host and restarted the server. 
and it seems to be fixed. Thanks for help to kick me for me to check the error logs.